# Getting a merged array after running map for a jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary, merge

After running a map for a jQuery collection I'm getting a 1-level array as if it merged everything.

However if I convert the collection to Array I get the expected result. What's the reason of such behavior?

https://jsfiddle.net/nytdL348/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let foobar = $('div').map(function(i,elem){
    return [1,2,3];
  })

  let text = JSON.stringify(foobar.toArray(), null);
  $('body').append(text)

  $('body').append("<br></br>")

  let foobar2 = $('div').toArray().map(function(i,elem){
    return [1,2,3];
  })

  let text2 = JSON.stringify(foobar2, null);
  $('body').append(text2)
});
```

Comment: The jQuery `.map()` method works that way on purpose, and in that respect it's different from the Array `.map()`.

Comment: can you attach any source that tells me that? I searched through the doc and couldn't find anything. From my point of view if the map returns a value to be inserted in the position, if a array is returned it should be inserted in the position

Comment: [It's right there in the jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: sorry but I still can't understand why

Comment: Well that's simply the way the jQuery team decided it should work. You'd have to ask them; I've always thought it was strange.

Comment: and for example, doing `let foo = $('div'); foo[0] = [1,2,3]`, or `foo.push([1,2,3,4])` I get the normal behaviour

Comment: Again, the only people who can explain why the jQuery `.map()` method works that way are the members of the jQuery team at the time the feature was implemented.

Comment: From the documentation I linked: *The function can return an individual data item or an array of data items to be inserted into the resulting set. If an array is returned, the elements inside the array are inserted into the set.*

Comment: Thanks for the quote on the doc